# Change cookie another coookie with javascript code

Tags: javascript

im trying to change  my cookie in the browser im using DVWA to practice but i cant upload the cookie to my browser to get the session.
My question is can i change my cookie to another cookie with javascript code and how ?
thank you

Answer (score 1):

You can set a cookie in JavaScript like this:

```
document.cookie = "username=newUsername";
```

This will overwrite any existing cookie called username. Just right click the page, inspect the page, open the console, paste the code, and press enter. Then you can read the page's cookies by running:

```
console.log(document.cookie);
```

Comment: thank you for the answer . i tried it it the cosole of the browser to change PHPSESSID to make session hijacking in DVWA ?